# PHP class property initialised as array becomes null in method

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have upgrade from I think PHP 5 to PHP 8.1 and now I'm updating the code to it. The title of the post is because I believe that the issue here has to be something about the variable `$mandatory_fields` not being accessible or something inside of the function.

I have this class:

```
class Form extends StandardOutput{
    var $fields = array();
    var $id;
    var $js;
    var $oid = 0;
    var $calendar_fields = array();
    var $opt_lang = true;
    var $field_oid = true;
    /**
        * $mandatory_fields array() für Pflichtfelder
        */
    var $mandatory_fields = array();
    function makeForm(){
        global $show,$subshow,$maxUploadSize,$csprache;
        if($show != 'anlegen')
        $rows = $this->getValues();
        //die('hier');
            
        parent::printStandard();
        $out = '';
        $temp = '';
        if(sizeof($this->mandatory_fields)>0){
            $out .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                        function checkForm(){';
            foreach($this->mandatory_fields as $key => $val){
```

And on the function sizeof($this->mandatory_fields) I'm getting an error of giving this function a null value. Why is it NULL when is well defined on the beginning of the class as an array().

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sizeof(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in...

I could fix it just by adding `is_countable()` as a second condition.

```php
if(is_countable($this->mandatory_fields) && sizeof($this->mandatory_fields)>0) {
```

That solves it but I still would like to understand why is it NULL.

Comment: I will update the title of the post as soon as I have some clarification to give a proper one.

Comment: You could initialize it in the `__construct()` method instead of the property declaration.

Comment: I tried. I get a new error that disorients me haha. I'm not sure if it's a new error and after creating the __construct the condition works well or it doesn't. After adding is_countable seems to work fine. I need to keep studying the code, is not my code D:
Still, I would like to understand why is null if it's declared as array right there.

Comment: If you don't specify visibility, your class variables will default to public. So you've probably got some code outside this class doing something like `$obj->mandatory_fields = some_function_that_returns_null();` It's getting properly defaulted to an empty array, but then it's being changed _after_ initialization.

Comment: This worked in before the upgrade?

Comment: Barmar: Good, question, pretty sure it did. I will have that answer tomorrow.
Alex: That property shows up just on these lines and one more time way down just as a condition. (  isset($this->mandatory_fields[$db_f])  ) It doesn't seem to be modified in any way.

Comment: Not reproducible unfortunately ~ https://3v4l.org/sFArg. I can only see @AlexHowansky's suggestion being applicable but without more code, there's no way to tell. Try using `private array $mandatory_fields = [];` then at least you'll get errors if something tries to change it

Comment: That was a good suggestion. I found something trying to change it. And it's defining it as a variable that is not referenced or defined anywhere.
Anyways seems that the issue was not just my ignorance, I thought that maybe there was something really simple that I didn't know. I will keep reading the code then.